# How to automatically close the ssh-agent along with closing Cygwin?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, process, bashrc, ssh-agent

I am on Windows 10 Pro.

I have added the following lines to my Cygwin (fully up-to-date) `~/.bashrc` file:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null
ssh-add > /dev/null 2>&1
```

in order for me not to have to do those each and every time as I typically don't do anything else than connect to Linux machines.

Notice, that I redirect the output of those commands to the *black hole* for me not really being interested in it, otherwise it would output something like:

```
Agent pid 11060
Identity added: /home/vlastimil/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/vlastimil/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

But, I noticed today, that for some reason, that those `ssh-agent.exe` processes remain in memory after I log out and close Cygwin.

Question is:

How to automatically close the `ssh-agent` along with closing Cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured, first thing to do, is in the `~/.bashrc` file, I need to save the output of:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Instead of discarding it; an example follows:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) > ~/.ssh-agent-stdout
```

---

Finally, create the following file:

```
~/.bash_logout
```

With contents:

```
ssh_agent_pid=$(awk '{ print $3 }' ~/.ssh-agent-stdout)
kill -HUP "$ssh_agent_pid"
```

Comment: I think this is no viable solution if you open multiple terminals. It would kill the ssh-agent for the other terminals, too.

Comment: @sweisgerber.dev I since have found out, there is `ssh-host-config` program in Cygwin ;)

Comment: I googled after @vlastimil 's short keyword comment and found: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC281 section: `5.4 Configuring SSH` this should help fellow `ssh-agent` configurators.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Would you mind shortly explaining the relationship between `ssh-host-config` and `ssh-agent`? `ssh-host-config` is for the *server* part, while `ssh-agent` deals with keys when we use a ssh *client*. Correct?

Comment: @sweisgerber.dev The link you gave does not contain the term `ssh-agent` at all. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

A small **.bashrc** improvement should also work for multiple sessions:

```
function cleanup {
  TTY=$(basename $(tty))
  if [ -f ~/.ssh-agent-stdout.${TTY} ]; then
    ssh_agent_pid=$(awk '{ print $3 }' ~/.ssh-agent-stdout.${TTY})
    kill -HUP "$ssh_agent_pid"
    rm -f ~/.ssh-agent-stdout.${TTY}
  fi
}

trap cleanup EXIT


TTY=$(basename $(tty))
eval $(ssh-agent) > ~/.ssh-agent-stdout.${TTY}
```

It does the same as in answer above, but it adds TTY number to pid file, so when trap triggers, the right ssh-agent will be killed.